# Qbs: How to run simple terminal command?

Tags: qt-creator, qbs

I'm used to working with Makefiles but my current project uses `.qbs` files. How do I run a simple terminal command through qbs without creating or requiring files? Similar to a phony rule in make.

The following works and shows "awesome" in my terminal.

```
import qbs 1.0

Project {
    name: "cli"

    Product {
        name: "helloworld"
        type: "application"
        files: "TEST.c"
        Depends { name: "cpp" }
    }

    Product {

        type: ["custom-image"]
        Depends { name: "helloworld" }

        Rule {
            inputsFromDependencies: ["application"]
            Artifact {
                fileTags: ["custom-image"]
            }
            prepare: {
                var cmd = new Command("echo", "awesome")
                return cmd
            }
        }
    }
}
```

However I have to touch my dummy `TEST.c` file before each run. Without the `helloworld` dependency the Rule does not run.

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

It's buried in the documentation in a very non obvious place and further obscured by Command (which is not the correct way, lol). I've had your problem too.

What you need is this:
http://doc.qt.io/qbs/jsextension-process.html

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what your end goal is but you could use `Transformer{}` instead of a `Rule{}`. The biggest difference between a `Rule{}` and a `Transformer{}` is you don't need any inputs for the `Transformer{}` to run.

Also see `Transformer.alwaysRun` property.

https://doc.qt.io/qbs/transformer-item.html